# How much memory required when Value Type is Boxed into Reference Type in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

```
public class A
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       int num = 13; // It stores in Stack and takes 4 bytes
       object obj = 13; // Where it is Stored (Stack or Heap)? 
       //How much size obj require?
    }
}
```

I just want to know the extra bits required for obj and why ?

Comment: `num` may or may not be stored in the stack. In fact for your program it is likely it won't be stored at all when run in release mode without the debugger attached as the compiler will detect that `num` is never used and will never store the value. What are you doing that knowing the answer to your question will effect your design choices?

Comment: Thanks Scott, for the knowledge but Let's suppose it is used in program later on , I just need to know the memory difference.

Comment: The memory difference = unimportant. You shouldn't need boxed values in large numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First to help explain the "why", from the C# 5 Specification: Section 4.3.1 Boxing conversions

> The actual process of boxing a value of a non-nullable-value-type is
>   best explained by imagining the existence of a generic boxing class,
>   which behaves as if it were declared as follows:
>
> ```
> sealed class Box<T>: System.ValueType
> {
>   T value;
>   public Box(T t) {
>       value = t;
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Boxing of a value v of type T now consists of executing the expression
>   new Box(v), and returning the resulting instance as a value of type
>   object. Thus, the statements
>
> ```
> int i = 123;
> object box = i;
> ```
>
> conceptually correspond to
>
> ```
> int i = 123;
> object box = new Box<int>(i);
> ```

To answer if it is stored on the stack or the heap, the answer is both. See [Boxing and Unboxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) on the MSDN.

> Consider the following declaration of a value-type variable:
>
> ```
> int i = 123;
> ```
>
> The following statement implicitly applies the boxing operation on the
>   variable i:
>
> ```
> // Boxing copies the value of i into object o. 
> object o = i;
> ```
>
> The result of this statement is creating an object reference o, on the
>   stack, that references a value of the type int, on the heap. This
>   value is a copy of the value-type value assigned to the variable i.
>   The difference between the two variables, i and o, is illustrated in
>   the following figure.   [image]

So on the stack there are `sizeof(Object)` bytes stored, and on the heap there are `sizeof(int)` + Class overhead stored.

I could not find any good documentation on how large that overhead is, it is most likely 8 to 16 bytes in size.

Comment: I am fairly certain that calculation is wrong. Each object has much higher overhead than the pointer size.

Comment: @DiveshPal Instead of saying "Thanks" please upvote the answer if it was helpful and if you feel you have had your question answered click the check mark next to the question that you feel best answers your question.

Answer (score 5):

According to [this article](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/object-overhead-the-hidden-.net-memory--allocation-cost/) the header for each object is 8 bytes on 32 bit systems and 16 bytes on 64 bit systems. This means that your boxed int will take **12 bytes on the heap and 4 bytes reference on the stack on 32 bit system and 20 bytes on the heap and 8 bytes on the stack on 64 bit system**. However as per @Hans Passant's comment the objects must be aligned to multiples of 4 bytes in 32 bit mode and multiples of 8 bytes in 64 bytes which would make **the 64 bit version take 24 bytes**.

It should be noted that this is an implementation detail and can change in the future. In general it is strange that you would care about this. The CPU time is usually much bigger problem than memory when dealing with value types as boxing puts load on the GC and requires additional operations to use the object.

Comment: That's almost accurate, you forgot about padding however.  Just document that object sizes are a multiple of 4 in 32-bit, a multiple of 8 in 64-bit.  Which adds 4 bytes of padding to the boxed int in 64-bit mode, it is 24 bytes.  A boxed byte is the more interesting case, 3 bytes of padding in 32-bit mode, 7 bytes of padding in 64-bit mode.